# How to align 2 li's next to each other

Tags: css, alignment, html-lists

This is some easy code to explain what I need:

```
<ul>
<%
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
%>
    <li>test<%=i%></li>
<%
  }
%>
</ul>
```

Now, standard the li's will be displayed like this

test0
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5

I want them to be displayed like this

test0 test2 test4 
test1 test3 test5

It's probably possible with css but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to let the first first three lis float to the left, and then, for the fourth one, use "clear : both" so that the line breaks, and then do the same thing for the last one...

```
<ul>
 <li style="float : left">A</li>
 <li style="float : left">B</li>
 <li style="float : left">C</li>
 <li style="clear : both ; float : left">D</li>
 <li style="float : left">E</li>
 <li style="float : left">F</li>
 <li style="float : left">G</li>
</ul>
```

You have the index of the li in the loop, so using "i % 4 == 0" should do the trick..